# Ошибка при создании оконного приложения на winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

```
LRESULT WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparm, LPARAM lparm)
{
    if(message == WM_DESTROY)
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
    else
    {
        DefWindowProcA(hwnd, msg, wparm, lparm);
    }

}

int main()
{
    WNDCLASSA wcl;
    memset(&wcl, 0, sizeof(wcl));
    wcl.lpszClassName = "ClassName";
    wcl.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;

}
```

Когда я написал такой код в `Visual Studio` у меня возникла ошибка

```
a value of type "LRESULT(*)(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparm, LPARAM lparm)" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "WNDPROC"
```

Но когда я изменил режим с x86 на x64 то ошибка пропала. Что мне нужно сделать что-бы работало и на x86 и на x64?

Comment: `LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc` чтобы у функции было соглашение stdcall, как то требуется для функций обратного вызова, использующихся в WinAPI.

Comment: ну ещё хорошо писать функции без A/W  в конце. Или если уже пишете, то у всех апи функций писать. Иначе могут быть самые чудные спецэффекты.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Прежде всего, для оконных приложений Windows нужно использовать функцию WinMain вместо main, которая в Windows используется только для консольных приложений (это наследство операционной системы MS DOS).
Во-вторых, в объявлении оконной процедуры нужно использовать спецификатор CALLBACK: `LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc`. В-третьих, проверьте, что подключен заголовок windows.h: `#include <windows.h>`.